# How do I change/switch background color of footer automatically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my footer background color to change automatically every second. How can I do this using JavaScript?
https://www.minus99.com/ I want to make the footer color change like of the website in the given link.

I tried this code but it is not working.

```
<footer onload="change()" id="background">
    <a href="">me@gmail.com</a><br>
    +977 98088950**5<br>Kapurdhara<br>
    Kathmandu<br>Nepal<br>
    &copy;-PratisthaKansakar<br>       
</footer>

<script>
        var i = 0;
        var color = Array[black,blue, green];
        function change() {
            var doc = document.getElementById("background");

            doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
            i = i+1;
            if(i>2){
                i=0;
            }
        }
        setTimeout(change, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you do inspect element and check it out how they've done it? PS: they are using CSS animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery UI and animate with a simple timer you can achieve it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
 setInterval(function() {
    $('#footer')
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' },1000)
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'green' }, 1000) 
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 1000) 
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'blue' }, 1000) 
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'Olive' }, 1000) 
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'Purple' }, 1000) 
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'Navy' }, 1000) 
    .animate( { backgroundColor: 'Fuchsia' }, 1000);
    }, 1000);

 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<footer id="footer">
kansakarpratistha@gmail.com
<br/>
+977 98088950**5
<br/>
Kapurdhara
<br/>
Kathmandu
<br/>
Nepal
<br/>
©-PratisthaKansakar
</footer >
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the timeout again and again (setInterval can be used instead), it is being called only once, and give the name of the colors in the array as strings

```js
var i = 0;
var color = ['black', 'blue', 'green'];

function change() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("background");
  console.log("called")
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = i + 1;
  if (i > 2) {
    i = 0;
  }
  a()
}

function a() {
  return setTimeout(change, 1000);
}
a();
```

```html
<footer id="background">aaaaaaaaaa</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `['black', 'blue', 'green']` format for array and use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

> The `setInterval()` method, offered on the Window and Worker interfaces,
>   repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call. It returns an interval ID which uniquely
>   identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling
>   `clearInterval()`. This method is defined by the
>   WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin.

```js
var i = 0;
var color = ['black', 'blue', 'green'];

function change() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("background");
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = i + 1;
  if (i > 2) {
    i = 0;
  }
}
setInterval(change, 1000);
```

```html
<footer onload="change()" id="background">
  <a href="">me@gmail.com</a><br> +977 98088950**5<br>Kapurdhara<br> Kathmandu
  <br>Nepal<br> &copy;-PratisthaKansakar
  <br>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` fires once.

`setInterval` fires continuously

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with this code :

```
<script>
    var footer = document.getElementById('background');
    var colors = ['black', 'blue', 'green'];
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        footer.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        i = (++i) % colors.length;
    }, 1000);
</script>
```